# odoo8 Field year selection with today year as default

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I want to make a year selection where the default year is now.
This is my .py

```
def get_years():
    year_list = []
    for i in range(2022, 2036):
        year_list.append((i, str(i)))
    return year_list    

def get_year(self):
    return str(datetime.now().year)

year = fields.Selection(get_years(), string='Year', default=get_year)
```

and this is my .xml

```
<field name="year">
```

But I get this error

```
ValueError: Wrong value for wizard.report.purchase.tracking.year: '2023'
```

What should I do? 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the string type key and pair value of touple for the selection field.

```
def get_years():
    year_list = []
    for i in range(2022, 2036):
        year_list.append((str(i), str(i)))
    return year_list
```

also You can set default value directly at selection.

```
year = fields.Selection(get_years(), string='Year', default=str(datetime.now().year))
```